# TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an error that I can't find the solution and I don't have to use jQuery; I don't have any div with submit as name

My code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<head>    
<script>    
function formSubmit()    
{    
     document.getElementById('web').submit();    
}    
</script>    
</head>    
<body>    
<form action="class003.php" id="g_form" method="POST">    
<input type="text" name="f1" value="">    
</form>    
<div id="web" onclick="formSubmit()">click</div>    
</body>    
</html>
```

on chrom I'm getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).submit is not a
>   function
>       at formSubmit (test2.html:8)
>       at HTMLDivElement.onclick (test2.html:19)

on Firefox the same error

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function[Learn
>   More]

Answer (score 4):

You need to submit `form` not the `div`

Make it

```
document.getElementById('g_form').submit();
```

Answer (score 3):

You mistyped the `id` of your element. It should be `g_form`.

```
function formSubmit()    
{    
     document.getElementById('g_form').submit();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You using **id** of Your `div` but for submitting the form You need to specify the id of Your `Form` element

So just change the

```
function formSubmit()    
{    
     document.getElementById('g_form').submit();    // Change the Id here
}
```

Hopes It will help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<head>    
<script>    
function formSubmit()    
{    
     document.getElementById('g_form').submit();    // Change the Id here
}    
</script>    
</head>    
<body>    
<form action="class003.php" id="g_form" method="POST">    
<input type="text" name="f1" value="">    
</form>    
<div id="web" onclick="formSubmit()">click</div>    
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<head>    
<script>    
function formSubmit()    
{    
     document.forms['g_form'].submit();
}    
</script>    
</head>    
<body>      

<form action="class003.php" id="g_form" name="g_form" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="f1" value=""> 

</form>
 <div class="button1" onClick="formSubmit();">Click</div>
</body>    
</html>
```