# php curl populating variables with html drop down selection

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl, html-select

I am new to php and trying to get a php curl request variable to be populated from a html drop down form. I want this request to reload the page upon selection. The following code below give this error

> select.php:19 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit
>   is not a function
>       at change (select.php:19)
>       at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (select.php:10)

```
<html>          
<head>
</head>

<body>

 <form method="post">
 <select id="wipname2" name="wipname2" style='position: relative' onchange="change()">
     <option value="site1.com">site1.com</option>
     <option value="site2.com">site2.com</option>
     <option value="site3.com">site3.com </option>
 </select>
 </form>

 <script>
 function change(){
     document.getElementById("wipname2").submit();
 }
 </script>

<?php

 $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  //CURLOPT_URL => 'https://example.com/MagicService/rest/ltmNode?wipNames='.$_GET["wipnames2"],
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/MagicService/rest/ltmNode?wipNames=".'$_GET["wipnames2"]',
// CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/MagicService/rest/ltmNode?wipNames=content.gslb.fmr.com",
//  CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/MagicService/rest/ltmNode?wipNames=$value",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "access-token: df11c69eabb9eab4abaf4bcc6b1e62a26025e830",
    "password: ",
    "username: "
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
        //fwrite($output,$response);
//print_r (explode(" ",$response));
echo $response;

}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can change `<form method="post">` to `<form id="theForm" method="post">` and then change `document.getElementById("wipname2").submit();` to `document.getElementById("theForm").submit();`

Comment: Thanks @Hackerman this worked perfectly

Comment: @Glad to help!!

Comment: please don't post answers in the comment section.

Comment: can anyone explain why the url is not working with this at the end '.$_GET["theForm"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this piece of code `document.getElementById("wipname2").submit();`. `wipname` is a `select` control, and it doesn't have a `submit` event. But you have that control inside a `form`, so you can make that work with just some minor changes:

1. You can change `<form method="post">` to `<form id="theForm" method="post">` in order to add an identifier(`id`) to your form.
2. And then change `document.getElementById("wipname2").submit();` in your `change` function, to `document.getElementById("theForm").submit();` in order to trigger your `form` submit event.

Answer (score 1):

`submit()` is a reference to the text input with `name="submit"` in form.

put `<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submit" />` inside form and then it will work.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43338230/typeerror-document-getelementbyid-submit-is-not-a-function?rq=1)